# ember.js charts view backed with data from the server

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to do the following with ember.js

I want a single route to display twice the same view which represents a google pie chart.

I defined my view and coded the template like this

```
{{view App.MyView identifier:1}}
{{view App.MyView identifier:2}}
```

I want each of this view to query the server for a specific resource and get the chart data from there. Let's say

```
/charts/1.json
/charts/2.json
```

But both of these views have the same controller, inherited from the single route.

I don't know how to back each view with its own set of data ...

I am using ember.js 1.0.0.rc6 with ember-data 0.13 and ember-rails 0.12.0 at the moment.

I am doing things correctly here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `{{control}}` helper to render with a fresh controller instance every time.

However this may not be be what you need here. It appears to me you have `/charts` Route that has charts data from `/charts/1..N.json`. But you want to show the individual charts without going to a `/charts/1..` Routes. ie:- the charts render at `/charts` itself.

One way to model this is to load the list of charts via `/charts` Route. And the `charts` template render the charts within an `#each` or manually with `render`.

If your `/charts` api call returns data for each chart, you are done, you simple render that data in the `chart` template passing the data to the custom View.

If the chart data is separate and not part of `/charts` then you will need to load it separately in the `ChartController` and then pass it to the custom View.

I made a basic [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/eyaqir/7) with this idea.

Comment: Thx Darshan for those ideas. Isn't it possible to have each view backed by its own controller, which in turn would query its data?

Comment: The [`{{control}}`](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-control-code-helper) helper does this.